# current MySql Connection Limit Expansion

Tags: mysql, cpanel

This message is intended to notify you that you have reached your concurrent MySQL connection limit. Please read the information below.

User: myuserid
Domain: mydomainname
MySQL Connection Limit:
Current MySQL Connection 72

I'm concerned about how to regulate it. The notification above was sent to me by my shared web hosting server. How can I prevent an external client from connecting to my database? Please assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix your code to limit total MySQL connections. Also make sure that you are closing MySQL connection whenever it is not required in your code.